# Wrap asynchronous code in a blocking call

Tags: scala

I'm inserting a record in MongoDB :

```
val observable: Observable[Completed] = collection.insertOne(doc)

observable.subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {
  override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = { println("Inserted"); }
  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = { println(" \n\nFailed " + e + "\n\n"); fail() }
  override def onComplete(): Unit = { println("Completed"); }
})
```

The test passes even though the `onError` callback is invoked. This is because `insertOne` is an asynchronous method and the test completes before the `onError` is invoked. I would like to wrap the insertOne method into a blocking call, so `subscribe` is not invoked until after `observable` value is set.

Is there an idiomatic method to achieve this is in Scala ?

Comment: You can have a look at [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach to synchronously block the async operation is using [`Await.result`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await$@result[T](awaitable:scala.concurrent.Awaitable[T],atMost:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration):T) on a `Future`. Since [`MongoCollection.insertOne`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/scaladoc/index.html#org.mongodb.scala.MongoCollection@insertOne(document:TResult):org.mongodb.scala.Observable[org.mongodb.scala.Completed]) returns an `Observable[Complete]`, you can use the implicit [`ScalaObservable.toFuture`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/scaladoc/index.html#org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ScalaObservable@toFuture():scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[T]]) on it:

```
val observable = collection.insertOne(doc)
Await.result(observable.toFuture, Duration.Inf)

observable.subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {
  override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = { println("Inserted"); }
  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = { println(" \n\nFailed " + e + "\n\n"); fail() }
  override def onComplete(): Unit = { println("Completed"); }
})
```

Comment: should result contain an observable that I subscribe to?

Comment: `result` should already be a `Seq[T]`, meaning a `Seq[Completed]` instance.

Comment: should result not be type Observable[Completed] as this is returned by 'collection.insertOne(doc)' ?

Comment: @blue-sky Not when you call `toFuture` on it. I've updated my answer as I think I misunderstood what you needed. The solution now starts the observable and then calls `toFuture` on it to allow you to wait until it completes. Then, it registers with the observable.